# binary search in array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, binary-search

I have an array of objects :

```
array = [
  {
    name:'alex',   
    number:36783712773
  },
  {
    name:'gabe',   
    number:99938873,
  },
and so on like this
]
```

I know the basic concept of binary search and how it works but most of the examples of the internet deal with an array of numbers so I cannot figure out to search by name and phone through the array of objects.

I can search from the backend but I do not want to make unnecessary HTTP calls for a thing that can easily be dealt with in javascript.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to choose either `name` or `number` for binary search over a specific array, and then the array that you are searching ***must*** be first sorted by that value. If you can't satisfy this requirement (you'll need to maintain 2 separate sorted arrays if you want to search by 2 different fields), then you're probably [barking up the wrong tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree).

Comment: okay, so let's say I want to search by name only so if I understand you correctly first I have to sort by name and then just do comparing as it happens in simple binary search function

Comment: I suppose , all you need is filter method of Array, you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and you don't have to write any algoritm

Comment: @Yaroslav yes I can do it and I did do that but the worst-case scenario of linear search as you are suggesting to implement is very bad when it comes to big objects and gonna cause some serious performance issues and that is not very scalable that is why I am using binary search to make it efficient and scalable.

Comment: @AzanKorejo Yes, binary search on names once the data is sorted by name key

Comment: Well, Thank You all of you i think i got what is needed thanks again for your time and skill.

Comment: Please note that @trincot's analysis is unfortunately marred by a bad implementation of the test cases.   His binary search is faster than `.find` even for 1000 entries, once that's fixed.

Comment: And also note that @trincot has now fixed this error.  Unsurprisingly, binary search quickly surpasses a linear search, in my runs somewhere between 10 and 100 entries.  Thanks trincot for the deep analysis and your quick fix of the problem!

Comment: Voted to reopen as, while this asks for a tutorial reference, it also asks for direct help.  The answer from trincot shows a useful approach.  While the question *should* have shown attempts from the OP, it's still a reasonable question without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below an implementation of binary search.

In the previous version of this answer there was a huge bug in generating the test cases. The updated version shows the supremacy of binary search compared to a linear search, already when using small arrays.

Here is a script that times the execution of both linear search and binary search on arrays of objects. First on an array of 10 objects, then 100, 1000, and finally 10 000:

```js
function binarySearch(array, target) {
    let lo = 0, hi = array.length;
    while (lo < hi) {
        let mi = (lo + hi) >> 1;
        let diff = target - array[mi].number;
        if (diff === 0) return array[mi];
        else if (diff < 0) hi = mi;
        else lo = mi + 1;
    }
}

function linearSearch(array, target) {
    return array.find(o => o.number === target);
}

function test(searchFunc, array, searchValues, times) {
    let accTime = 0;
    for (let time = 0; time < times; time++) { // Time the execution several times
        let now = performance.now();
        for (let number of searchValues) {
            let match = searchFunc(array, number);
            if (!match) throw "err";
        }
        accTime += performance.now() - now;
    }
    return accTime / times; // ... and take average
}

for (let length = 10; length < 1e5; length *= 10)
{
    let array = Array.from({length}, (_, number) =>
        ({ name: "alex", ismember: true, number: number * 100 + 13 })
    );
    let searchValues = Array.from({length: 10000}, () =>
        Math.floor(length * Math.random()) * 100 + 13
    );
    // First a dry run
    let linearSearchTime = test(linearSearch, array, searchValues, 2);
    let binarySearchTime = test(binarySearch, array, searchValues, 2);
    // The real run
    linearSearchTime = test(linearSearch, array, searchValues, 5);
    binarySearchTime = test(binarySearch, array, searchValues, 5);
    console.log({length, binarySearchTime, linearSearchTime});
}
```

### Different searchable properties

If you want to use binary search sometimes by one property, and sometimes by another, then you'll need to create separate "indexes" referring to your data, each sorted by the relevant property.

So for instance:

```js
let data = [
    { name: "alex", number: 13 },
    { name: "helen", number: 10 },
    { name: "zoe", number: 11 },
    { name: "willy", number: 12 },
];

let index = Object.fromEntries(["name", "number"].map(prop => [
    prop,
    data.map(o => [o[prop], o])
        .sort(([a], [b]) => (a > b) - (a < b))
]));

function binarySearch(array, target) {
    let lo = 0, hi = array.length;
    while (lo < hi) {
        let mi = (lo + hi) >> 1;
        let key = array[mi][0]; 
        if (key === target) return array[mi][1]; // the actual data
        else if (key > target) hi = mi;
        else lo = mi + 1;
    }
}

// demo
console.log(binarySearch(index.name, "willy"));
console.log(binarySearch(index.name, "zoe"));
console.log(binarySearch(index.name, "alex"));
console.log(binarySearch(index.name, "helen"));
console.log(binarySearch(index.number, 13));
console.log(binarySearch(index.number, 12));
console.log(binarySearch(index.number, 11));
console.log(binarySearch(index.number, 10));
```

Comment: well, that's interesting I did not know the power of the linear search until now which kinda makes me undo all the code I just wrote :(

Well, guess gotta do it .

Thank you Trincot for the code example and making me realize the blunder i was going to create and deploy.

Comment: There's a real bug in these test cases.  `Array.from({length: 10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random(length)) * 100 + 13)` just returns an array of ten thousand copies of `13`.

Comment: ... and once that's fixed, the numbers are very, very different.  And binary search wins even at 1000 elements.

Comment: OOps, that is really a bad bug there.

Comment: what is happening? now I have to redo my code ??

Comment: My sincere apologies. There was a huge bug in this code that Scott detected, which gave a completely wrong impression of how the two algorithms compare. This is now updated. Binary search is the way to go, also in JavaScript. Again, my apologies.

Comment: well, guess the last decision is to redo it and go with binary search btw thank you all especially @ScottSauyet I just went with matrics and did not bother much on the code so thanks for your help.

Comment: It's okay @trincot it happens to all of us. I'll just press my favourite buttons [ctrl+z].

Comment: Lol, hope you have long enough history in your editor ;)

Comment: @trincot Hail Github

Comment: @AzanKorejo: I was surprised by the findings, but because trincot is to me a very trusted source my first thought was that my understanding of the algorithms might be faulty.  The only reason I noticed it was because the linear search was growing way too slowly as the input grew ten-fold.  It took a while to find the culprit, as it accidentally used a technique familiar from other languages.  Please keep in mind that binary search is only going to be useful in the case that the data is already sorted.  If you have to sort first, then search, it will take longer than the linear search!

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah, I was a bit shocked too at first but unlike you, I decided to accept the reality and go with the linear search until I saw your comment and trincot fixed it and as for the sorting, I am doing that in the DB query.

Comment: @AzanKorejo, I added a section on searching by different properties, which was the core of your question.

Comment: that's lovely and very kind of you, thank you @trincot